# AWS Cognito hosted UI integration with a payment system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use AWS Cognito hosted UI to authenticate & register users on to my web platform.

The registration journey is as follows - I have a single subscription plan.  A user wishes to purchase the subscription. He goes through the Cognito UI registration screens & in the end, the user completes the registration process. At the end of this process, I want to redirect the user to a payment portal to complete the payment.

I'm looking to achieve 2 things -

1. Integrate this registration journey with a payment portal
2. Once the payment is complete, get Cognito to mark the user as "registered". I'm fine if this has to be handled separately. I wouldn't mind maintaining a subscription status database myself if need be.

Comment: You can only customize the CSS of the hosted UI. To achieve what you want you would have to be able to edit the html and/or javascript.

Comment: Thanks Ninad. IF you post your comment as answer, I'll accept & close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only customize the CSS of the hosted UI. To achieve what you want you would have to be able to edit the html and/or javascript